# udemy course ai cannot continue installation matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

great thanks but nnow when i do pip3 install pyplot

it says: could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyplot

Sorry quite noob still in this area but willing to do great things :)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking questions. "I tried different things but nothing works" makes it impossible to guess what you tried, why it failed, or what you should have done differently.

Answer (score -1):

`pip install numpy` usually does the trick. Note, that you have to be in `venv` already when doing it, otherwise it tries to load it to outside of the virtual environment.

What comes to "matplotlib.pyplot" `pyplot` and `matplotlib` are separate modules.

->

`pip install matplotlib`

`pip install pyplot`

in map.py:

```
import matplotlib
import pyplot
```

Comment: sorry yes i fugured that out now but now I have another problem :(

Comment: Please vote answer up, because if user gets too many votes down he/she will be banned to answer questions...